# Why was Turkey allowed to keep Constantinople after WW1?

Tags: world-war-one, turkey, greece

Why was Turkey allowed to keep Constantinople after WW1? Greece was on the winning side, weren't they? Wouldn't it have made sense for the European great powers to support a Greek demand on Constantinople? After all, the Greeks are European, and Christian, and the European culture and civilisation traces its roots back to ancient Greece.

Comment: I’ve flagged this for closure as unclear as it shows a lack of appropriate basic research. It is also pushing a strong nationalist opinion and appears to exist only to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the reason for WW1 (an assassination of an individual that culminated in declarations of war based on alliances), these were not conflicts to gain territory. It would be unfounded to claim a city with Turkish inhabitans from Turkey as reparations.

Part of Turkey is also European. Some Turks are Christians too. And I don’t see how the roots of European culture are traced back to Ancient Greece. European peoples had their own cultures. Ancient Greece had an influence in spreading civilization. But would these influences be reasons to support a hypothetical illegal claim on a foreign city by Greece? That makes no sense.

Comment: Wasn't there a large Greek minority living in Istanbul at the time? Turkey and Greece "exchanged" large populations (expelled) around 1920.

Comment: What is a large minority. A minority is always small or smaller.

Comment: 277 000 hits on Google. https://www.google.se/search?q="a+large+minority"

Comment: @Ajagar: If the total population is say 100,000, then a large minority is around 30,000 to 40,000, while a small minority would be 3,000 - 4,000.

Answer (score 3):

**[Constantinople was founded by the Roman Emperor Constantine the Great in 330 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople)**.
It was the capital of the **[Byzantine Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire)** (Eastern Roman Empire) not Greek.  Constantinople was **[renamed to Istanbul](https://english.mojahedin.org/eventsen/203/The-naming-of-Constantinople-(Istanbul))** when the Ottoman's conquered the Byzantine Empire.   **[Constantinople fell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople)** April 6th, 1453.  From that time onward it was a Muslim city controlled by the Turks.  First under Ottoman control and finally under secular Turkish control beginning in 1908.

The City never belonged to Greece. Greece was neutral for much of WWI.
**[The Hellenistic government was overthrown in 1916](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greece_during_World_War_I#Greece_joins_the_war_(1916-17))** and the new government did declared war on the Central Powers in June of 1916 while it's own civil war was ongoing.  The new Greek government did want control of Constantinople after the war but Russia veto'd this.

> **[The Constantinople Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople_Agreement)**
>    The Greek government was neutral, but in 1915 it negotiated with the Allies, offering soldiers and especially a geographical launching point for attacks on the Straits. Greece itself wanted control of Constantinople. Russia vetoed the Greek proposal, because its main war goal was to control the Straits, and take control of Constantinople.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople) The UK and France both agreed, while putting forward their own claims, to an increased sphere of influence in Iran in the case of the UK and to annexation of Syria (including Palestine) and Cilicia for France. The UK and French claims were both agreed all sides also agreeing that the exact governance of the Holy Places was to be left for later settlement.

**[The Constantinople Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantinople_Agreement)** were a series of secret assurances in which the allies had agreed to give Constantinople and the Dardanelles to Russia.  Although Constantinople was occupied by the Allies at the end of WWI in 1918, Russia had experienced the Communist Revolution, withdrawn from the war and was no longer considered one of the Allied Powers.

Comment: So, basically, "because the commie revolution happened"!

Comment: @OlegLobachev I read it as Russia would have had a pretty significant claim on it had the Communist Revolution not knocked them out of the war.   But even when that that happened..  they didn't really consider giving it to Greece.

Comment: Well, Russian Empire had always had this idée fixe about having access to Mediterranean. Or any non-freezing open sea, in fact. This, plus the obvious religious aspect of "saving" the foundation of Orthodox church. I'd imagine that some secret talks went like "What do you want, if you give us _X_?" – "Constantinople!" Another issue is if Russia would indeed get Constantinople, if they stayed in Entente.

Comment: The Byzantine empire was ethnically heavily influenced by Greece. The inhabitants spoke Greek, the religion was called greek-orthodox and so on. It didn't disappear just because of the conquest 1453.

Comment: @OlegLobachev,  Agree on Russia always wanting a warm water port and most especially Black Sea ports and then control of the Dardanelles.

Comment: @hensti, Good points.   While not the official language, (Byzantine's official language was Latin),  Greek was widely spoken, taught and used.

Comment: @JMS I am surprised to hear that the official language was latin. Even after the fall of the western part of the empire? A lot (Most? All?) literature, administrative and religious documents and so on was written in Greek, weren't they? And the emperors and generals mostly had Greek names.

Comment: @hensti.  I'm learning a lot with your comments.  Again good point.  Western Roman Empire fell for the last time in 476 C.E.    Greek did become the official language.  Under the reign of Heraclius several hundred years latter (610–641).  The Empire's military and administration were restructured and adopted Greek for official use instead of Latin.  Nicely done.

Comment: @hensti,  I believe Byzantine adopted Greek not due to an allegiance with or influence by Greece but because it was economically and politically more expediant several hundred years after the fall of the western Roman Empire.   Greek was used in the Hellenistic kingdoms created by the division of Alexander’s empire among his heirs.  These kingdoms like Egypt and Palestine(Ptolemaic), Persia, Mesopotamia, Syria (Seleucid empire) and Macedonia (Antigonid) just eventually became important to Byzantium than was the shell of the Western Empire or Rome.